# How to set max smaller than min in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I need to present a chart for german school grades (best grade 1, worst 5).

I would like to have a Bar Chart that starts from 5 and goes to up 1, where 5 is the minimum value and 1 is the highest value on the Y-axis. In this way grade **1** (best grade) would result in a full bar and **5** (worst grade) in an empty bar.

The Y-axis should look like this:
[image]

I could not find an option to set this in ChartJS. How can I set a range where the min value is higher than the max value?

Answer (score 0):

```
yAxes: [
    {
        reverse: true, // will reverse the scale
    }
]
```

Comment: This does actually just turn te whole graph upside down, which is not what I want to achieve. Take a look at the picture I posted.